# Mailing functionality in Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress, feed, mailchimp, mailing

I am working on a horoscope website project which requires implementing a mailing functionality in the wordpress website. It requires these functionalities.

1. It requires users to sign-up for daily horoscope newsletter
2. A daily RSS feed should be looked up from the client automatically, which has the horoscope of all zodiac stars for that day. The data should be extracted from it.
3. A daily horoscope email sent to the users based on their zodiac sign.(As extracted from the xml Feed)

The client prefers it be done from mailchimp api.

Right now I am clueless on how to implement that. Can anyone help me out what will be best and easiest way to implement that.

Any help in this regard will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I would create my own solution using some webframework like Ruby on Rails... You would have to create a lot of custom code to change the wordpress's funtionality and then you are not as flexible as you would be with a custom solution.

Comment: Does it require a lot of work? What would you charge for implementing this stuff?

Comment: It isn't that easy. It will require lot's of work - regardless if you would like to use wordpress and write plugins or creating your own app. I would say the implementation would cost at least 5.000$ or more - if you would like to have a professional solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same query as you for something I had been working on. 
You could generate the HTML code for a feed by using [this tool](http://www.rss-info.com/en_rssinclude.html) and paste it onto the newsletter email (provided, of course, that it allows HTML embedding) and then mail it using MailChimp.

You might also want to use a [newsletter plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter/) instead.
I used a newsletter plugin that allows opt-in and can import addresses as well, depending on how your client wants it. The plugin also had capability to edit the HTML for the email so you could mail someone an entire post/rss or just some text if you wished. You can automate these functions as well so that they are mailed as often as you'd like with the content of your choice. I do not remember the exact name but I doubt that will be of concern.Quite a few of them are integrated with MailChimp and all of them can use the email cron if you prefer that.

Of course what you write on your own will be better suited but I suppose you can get the same thing using this suggestion.